# В чем косяк с cout?

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Подскажите, почему сообщение об ошибке выдается в любом случае и почему сразу четыре штуки? Где я накосячил?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

template <class T> void IntoNull(T a[], int n)
{
int A = 0;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
cout << "\nВведите А: "; cin >> A;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (A == a[i][j])
            {
                cout << "Есть.";
                break;
            }
        else
            cout << "Ошибка";
    }
}
template <class T> void Vvod(T a[], int n)
{
for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    for (int j = 0;j<n;j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = 0 + rand() % 5;
        cout << "\na[" << i << "][" << j << "]= " << a[i][j];
    }
}

void main()
{
int n = 2;
int a[2][2];
Vvod(a, n);
IntoNull(a, n);
_getch();
}
```

Comment: Косяк с cout в том, что косяка нет. Он делает ровно то, что вы говорите. У вас два вложенных цикла 0-n, что даст n^2 выполнений внутреннего. Дальше берите отладчик и смотрите что же именно вызывает несрабатывание условия.

Comment: Я перепробовал все возможные замены, но все осталось так же. Уже и не знаю, что сделать, чтобы исправить такую нелепую ошибку.

Comment: Отладчик в помощь. Без него вы не сможете писать что-то сложнее двух строк кода. PS. Особенно обратите внимание на содержимое a после Vvod(). И не используйте транслит...

Comment: @user196536: А вы и не должны бездумно пробовать все возможные замены. Или вы хотите экспериментальным путём проверить теорему о бесконечных обезьянах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишите циклы следующим образом

```
bool found = false;

for ( int i = 0; i < n && !found ; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < n && !found; j++ )
    {
        found = A == a[i][j];
    }
}

if ( found ) cout << "Есть.";
else cout << "Ошибка";
```